# Validate form field by onChange immediately, not after additional manipulations

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I have a simple form field with formik & yup validation.
The form is submitted by changing the form field. The field is of type text, but only numbers must be entered.
In this case, if a number exceeding `10` is entered, an error should be displayed and the form should be banned.

The problem is that the field only works after the blur.

If I enter one character (onChange) - field is not valid and "Required". Only after blur or type second symbol - valid.

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup
  .string()
  .trim()
  .required('Required')
  .test('amount', 'Test errror', (val) => {
    console.log('S1>>>' + val);
    return parseFloat(val) <= 10;
  }),
});

const handleSubmit = useCallback(async (values) => {
  try {
    console.log('Success');
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Unhandled login error :', e);
    }
  }, []);


<Formik
    validateOnChange
    initialValues={{ name: '' }}
    validationSchema={schema}
    onSubmit={handleSubmit}
  >
    {({
      values,
      errors,
      touched,
      handleChange,
      handleBlur,
      handleSubmit,
    }) => (
      <Form className="form" onChange={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="mb-4">
          <Form.Group className="position-relative">
            <div className="position-relative">
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                name="name"
                className={`${touched.name ? 'is-touch ' : ''} ${
                  errors.name && touched.name ? ' is-invalid' : ''
                } ${!errors.name && touched.name ? ' is-valid' : ''}`}
                value={values.name.replace(/\D/g, '')}
                onBlur={handleBlur}
                onChange={handleChange}
                placeholder="Name"
                touched={touched.name}
              />
            </div>
            {errors.name && (
              <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid" className="d-block">
                {errors.name}
              </Form.Control.Feedback>
            )}
          </Form.Group>
        </div>
      </Form>
    )}
  </Formik>
```

So, How to validate a form field already from the first character and without blur (only onChange) and if I type (without blur) `> 10` - show error?
Show error immediately, not after additional manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation, there are some props for these kind of manipulations.You can check **setFieldTouched** or **validateField** prop on this page:

https://formik.org/docs/api/formik